# Build a high quality telescope from scratch

Tags: telescope

I am interested in building a high quality portable telescope from scratch in an attempt to better understand how telescopes work. What kind of materials do I need? How would I go about putting the telescope together? Are there any online guides that you can recommend?

Comment: okarin, I would recommend breaking this down into separate questions. Perhaps this one can focus on what materials you need to build a portable telescope. If you desire a specific quality, you need to specific exactly what level of quality you seek.

Answer (score 4):

Amateur telescope making ([ATM](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=atm%20telescopes)) is a popular past-time for astronomers.

You can grind [your own](http://www.telescopemirrorblanks.com/) [mirror](http://www.newportglass.com/apxblank.htm), or you [can](http://www.rfroyce.com/stand_mirrors.htm) [buy](http://www.gs-telescope.com/content.asp?id=142) [ready](http://www.hubble-optics.com/index.html)-[made](http://www.orionoptics.co.uk/OPTICS/telescopemirrors.html) [mirrors](http://zambutomirrors.com/mirrors.html).

You can coat your mirrors with silver using chemical solutions yourself, or have a coating of aluminium applied using a vacuum chamber by an outfit offering such a service.

The main materials are a thick round slab of glass, usually Pyrex, and a smaller elliptical flat mirror. Using this you can make a Newtonian reflector. The support tube or structure for the mirrors can be one of a huge variety of designs, or you can be inventive yourself.

There are websites to guide you in this, such as [Mel Bartel's](http://www.bbastrodesigns.com/tm.html), [Stellafane](https://stellafane.org/tm/), and [AmateurTelescopeMaker.com](http://www.amateurtelescopemaker.com/).